# How to set oneof fields in node grpc

Tags: grpc-node

How do you use oneof fields in a grpc node? I am using dynamic code generation. I tried to modify the [quickstart](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/node/quickstart/) with

```
service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
  rpc SayHelloOneOf (OneOfRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

message OneOfRequest {
  oneof nameOneof {
    string name = 1;
  }
}
```

However I do not know how to set the name in the request in the client. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields in a `oneof` are still directly part of the message, so you can still represent that message with an object like this:

```js
{
  name: 'test name'
}
```

You can also set the field `nameOneof` to the value `"name"` to indicate which field of the `oneof` you are using.